# Laravel 4 - Call to a member function actividads() on a non-object (pivote table)

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table, relationships

I'm trying to save in my DB the relation between two tables `actividads` and `fichas` (through a pivot table: `actividad-ficha`. And I'm having this message:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)
>
> Call to a member function actividads() on a non-object

I pass through my Route two variables (ids):

```
Route::get('ficha/{id_ficha}/{id_actividad}', array('uses' => 'FichaController@enFicha'));
```

And then, in my 'FichaController':

```
public function enFicha($id_ficha, $id_actividad)
{
        $ficha = Ficha::find($id_ficha);
       // $actividad_id = Actividad::find($id_actividad); (doesnt work)
        $actividad_id = $id_actividad; 
        $ficha->actividads()->sync($actividad_id, false);

        return Redirect::route('actividads.index'); 
}
```

Here my models:

```
class Actividad extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();
public function fichas()
{       
    return $this->belongsToMany('Ficha', 'actividad_ficha')->withTimestamps(); //
}

class Ficha extends Eloquent {
protected $guarded = array();
public function actividads()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Actividad', 'actividad_ficha')->withTimestamps();
}
```

After change what @decco and @Ben suggested me, I have the next error message:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::formatSyncList() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webs/lara4/edu1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php on line 578 and defined
```

I don't know what is wrong with that... Any idea??

Thank you very much!!

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory. Change first line to: `$ficha = Ficha::find($id_ficha)`. And by the way, do you want to detach all other relations and leave only this one? Probably not, so use `sync($actividad_id, false)`

Comment: Now, I have the next error:  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webs/lara4/edu1/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 105 and defined

Comment: I've tried: $actividad_id = array(
    'id' => $id_actividad
    ); But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ficha = $id_ficha;
$ficha->actividads()->sync($actividad_id);
```

There's your problem. `$ficha` is a `String`, not an object.

Change the first line with `$ficha = Ficha::find($id_ficha)` which should return the `Ficha` object with ID `$ficha_id` or `null`.

Also you need to change the second line with `$ficha->actividads()->attach($actividad_id)`.

Comment: Now, I have the next error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::columnize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/webs/lara4/edu1/vendor/laravel/framework/s‌​rc/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 105 and defined –

Comment: I've tried: $actividad_id = array( 'id' => $id_actividad ); But it doesn't work!

Comment: That's because the `sync` method accepts an `array` of IDs as parameter, not a string and a boolean. You could use `attach` instead of `sync` which accepts a single ID as parameter. Please refer to the [laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) on how to properly use eloquent's methods.

Comment: @Ben `sync` accepts boolean as 2nd param which refers to `detaching`. 1st must be an array indeed.

Comment: Thank you both!! I solved it by: `$actividad = Actividad::find($id_actividad);
   $actividad_id = array($actividad->id);`